# Hash string function djb2 avoiding collisions properly?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hash

I am studying about hash string functions for a hasmap in javascript. And looking into this code that I found in the web, I am not sure if the function is correct or not:

```
HashMap._hashString = function(string) {
    var hash = 5381;
    for (var i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
        hash = (hash << 5) + hash + string.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = hash & hash;
    }
    //Reduce the chance of collisions by incorporating the string length,
    //and randomize the hashes to prevent malicious collisions.
    return hash ^ string.length ^ this._secret;
};
```

Does it make any sense to have this line?

```
        hash = hash & hash;
```

In this line of code:

```
    return hash ^ string.length ^ this._secret;
```

I understand that adding the length of the string as a factor for the hash to evaluate would help to work with the collisions, but why would I add this factor with a XOR operation? Why not using any other bit operator?

I am also reading about this article, to understand a bit more about the hash algorithms:

http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it make any sense to have this line?
>
> ```
>    hash = hash & hash;
> ```

The purpose of that line is to limit the value to the 32-bit range. `hash & hash` looks like a no-op, but applying bitwise operators will clip any overflow. It gives the same result as this:

```
 hash = hash & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

> In this line of code:
>
> ```
> return hash ^ string.length ^ this._secret;
> ```
>
> I understand that adding the length of the string as a factor for the hash to evaluate would help to work with the collisions, but why would I add this factor with a XOR operation? Why not using any other bit operator?

With `&` or `|` you would lose information: different inputs of the same length would have a bit higher chance of collision. In particular, an `&` with a length that is a power of 2, would be disastrous, as it could only yield 2 different values (the length itself or zero). Or an `|` with a length that has mostly 1 bits (like 0xffff): this would again limit the possible outcomes.

Doing a `+` would be a viable alternative, but then you would want to make sure the result remains in the 32-bit range again.

Comment: Is it common to try to limit the value to a 32 bit range?

Comment: It can be any size, but it should be fixed-sized. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) says: *"A hash function is any function that can be used to map data of arbitrary size to data of fixed size"*